# How to change the arrow color in UIPopoverPresentionController iOS 8?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

Question says it all. Does anyone know any tricks to change it from the standard grey color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to set the popover presentation controller's `backgroundColor`. If that isn't good enough, you can set its `popoverBackgroundViewClass`, which gives you total command of the chrome including the arrow (but is a lot more work to implement).

Comment: this was incredibly helpful, thank you !!!

Comment: ps im totally going to buy your book now

Comment: @Matt Really your answer solves my problem.Thank you!!!

Comment: Sory, this didn't work...

Comment: @MihailSalari It does work. If you have a question about specific code of yours, ask it as a question. I have sample code that demonstrates.

Comment: @MihailSalari Not sure what that means, but ok, no problem.